# Android service class variables

Tags: java, android, performance, memory

I have built a singleton utility class that holds a couple of android service variables. I did this to try to avoid needing to pass in a 'Context' reference each time I use a method in the class. Will keeping a reference to a service cause any problems?

```
public class ConnectivityUtil {

    // TODO: 5/24/2017 Is keeping a service as a member variable a good ida?
    private static ConnectivityUtil instance;
    private final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
    private final WifiManager wifiManager;

    private ConnectivityUtil(Context context) {
        connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    }

    public static void init(Context context) {
        instance = new ConnectivityUtil(context);
    }

    public static ConnectivityUtil getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that It'll be retained until your entire process is destroyed. Think of it as living as long as your application runs.

Comment: also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054416/is-it-beneficial-to-keep-a-member-reference-to-system-services-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what type of `Context` do you pass.

If you pass `Application Context` it is good practice:

inside service:

```
ConnectivityUtil.init(MyService.this.getApplicationContext());
```

If you pass Service directly

```
ConnectivityUtil.init(MyService.this);
```

You will get memory leak after service will be destroyed.

But **best** practice is init your singleton classes in Application class:

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ConnectivityUtil.init( getApplicationContext());
    }
}
```

So your `Singleton` will be created with application. Result is the same.

Comment: Thanks. I set up the class from the application class so I pass in an application context.